# Here android sdk - extend pre recorded voices list

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using Here android sdk, voice instructions for Turn-to-turn navigation. 
I tried [pre recorded voices](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics/coverage-navigation-voices.html), they works fine, but I wonder if I can somehow extend its list and add more pre-recorded voices? Is it supported somehow record my own voice for navigation and make it work with nav manager?

I know how to install additional tts voices, but interested in pre-recorded ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that is not supported. Only the skins HERE provides will work with the engine.